# Excel VBA - Correct VBA code for summing multiple rows

Tags: vba, excel

What is the correct way to code in VBA the below formula?  I need to sum 5 columns in a row in the 6th column, and do this for a total of 7 rows.

```
Range("G21").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("G21:G27"), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Comment: `ActiveSheet.Range("G21:G27").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(RC[-5]:RC[-1])"`

Comment: Aye did not realize that was simply all i was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to make it explicit, you can replace your three lines of code with @ScottCraner's suggestion. There's [seldom a need to `.Select`/`.Activate` a cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros)